# Search in already filled listview through textbox by eliminating all other rows except seacrhed row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have already populated a ListView from a DataTable dt4. I have declared globally and below is my code but code is not giving searched string instead its loading again on any keypress.

Please help me in writing code

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    conn = GetConnect()
    conn.Open()
    
    dt4.Select("ServiceName like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ")

    With ListView3
        .View = View.Details
        .GridLines = True
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add(" ", 30)
        .Columns.Add("CPT Code", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Service Name", 350, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

        For Each row As DataRow In dt4.Rows
            'Add Item to ListView.
            Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
            item.SubItems.Add(row("CPTCode").ToString())
            item.SubItems.Add(row("ServiceName").ToString())                
            item.Checked = False
            .Items.Add(item)
            item = Nothing
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `dt4` is loading again or `ListView3` is loading again?

Comment: I dont know exactly but its loading with full rows again and not searching any string

Comment: Yeah, you use the word `it` which can correspond to either of them, I am asking which one

Comment: Anyways how to refresh dt means datatable when its declared globally

Comment: I have never used DataTable but I did a quick search and may have found the answer, see my answer. Also it seems that you create a [database?] connection with each keystroke in the TextBox, which is extremely wasteful but I don't see how dt4 gets updated, but again I don't know about DataTables.

Comment: How to clear datatable with old values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of Select should have your sought rows

```
Dim rows = dt4.Select("ServiceName like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ")

For Each row As DataRow In rows
```

from [DataTable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0)

Comment: My data table i have declared globally, now problem is same data is repeating in Listview, How to clear that old data and enter new data into listview